# Scala - Extracting a value from a file containing data in JSON format

Tags: json, scala

I have a 'sample.json' file containing the following JSON data:

```
{"query": "SELECT count(*)  FROM TABLE_NAME"}
```

This file is being generated by another application and is placed in that application directory.

What I want to do is to read this file and extract the value (i.e., SELECT count(*)  FROM TABLE_NAME) of the key 'query' into a `val query`. This `val query` will be used to query a database.

Being new to Scala, I am quite lost in the other answers I have found. 
What is the simplest way to extract the value from the file into `val query`in Scala?

I would prefer not using any external libraries unless very necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are countless ways of parsing JSON in scala. For your particular task, here is one suggestion, assuming your JSON string has been read into the variable `jsonStr`:

```
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON

val resultOption = JSON.parseFull(jsonStr) match {
  case Some(map: Map[String, String]) => map.get("query")
  case _ => None
}
```

Now, if the parsing succeeded, `resultOption` will contain the SQL query string, wrapped in an [option](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html) (otherwise, it will be `None`). Next, you should probably check for errors, but for the sake of simplicity, if we blindly assume that everything worked out nicely, we can now access the final value as follows:

```
val query = resultOption.get
```